# Autocomplete not working inside a js file for import module from ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Autocomplete is not working in js file in VSCode, but if I import it into a ts file then it works, not sure whats wrong.

```
// my-ts.ts
export const m2 = (p: number) => p * 2;
export const m3 = (p: number) => p * 3;
export const m4 = (p: number) => p * 4;
```

here is js file

```
//my-js.js file
import * as helpers from './my-ts.ts';
helpers.[NO HINT HERE] 
helpers.anything(); // no error even here
```

here is the tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thats because your configuring your project for type script. I was writing TypeScript not to long ago, but latley Ive been back writing C++, but from what I remember, Its because of using things like source maps. The intellicode extensions (which I assume your using) is set up for TypeScript, which is a Typed